# How can i set HTML tags in wordpress page and user just need to put content.?

Tags: wordpress, custom-theme

I have converted HTML template in WordPress theme,

Now I need to set HTML tags in a custom field in WordPress page so the HTML tags are defined and the user just need to put content.

which plugin is better for my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create templates on theme folder, if the tags are other then the title and description then use Advance custom fields plugin for creating fields and then call it on template file.

Comment: Please describe more specifically and step by step

Comment: you can use this plugin [https://www.advancedcustomfields.com] for creating custom fields on backed.

Comment: and then you can create templates or default page and get the values of that field into any tags.